# c# my sql statement to lambda expression

Tags: c#, mysql, lambda

i have this sql statement :

```
 SELECT questionNo , ActivityID ,GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(Question, '[' , Answer , ']')
 SEPARATOR ' ')AS joined
 FROM question
 GROUP BY QuestionNo , ActivityID
 LIMIT 0,30
```

but i am using entity framework for MySQL and most of my class file methods are lambda , how do i convert this to lambda expression ?

BELOW-------------

```
public IList<Model.question> GetList()
    {
        IList<Model.question> lstRecords = context.questions.ToList();
        return lstRecords.GroupBy(x => new { x.QuestionNo, x.ActivityID }).Select(g => new { QuestionNo = g.Key.QuestionNo, ActivityID = g.Key.ActivityID, joined = string.Join(" ", g.Select(i => i.QuestionContent + "[" + i.Answer + "]"))});

    }
```

this is how i suppose to write it if i want to get list of it? it says cannot convert type ienumerable to ilist .

Comment: what would it even *mean* to convert that to a "lambda expression"? do you mean to *LINQ syntax*? or *LINQ operations using lambdas*? or...?

Comment: yes linq using lambda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try below

```
var result = question.GroupBy(x=>new{x.QuestionNo , x.ActivityID})
.Select(g=> new {QuestionNo= g.Key.QuestionNo, 
                 ActivityID= g.Key.ActivityID,
                 joined = string.Join(" ", g.Select(i=>i.Question+ "[" + i.Answer +"]"))})
.Take(30);
```

If you want to return this from method you can create new class like below

```
public class Question
{
    public int QuestionNo {get;set;} //change the type accordingly 
    public string ActivityID {get;set;} //change the type accordingly 
    public string joined {get;set;}   //change the type accordingly 
}
```

and change the method to :

```
public IList<Question> GetList()
{
    IList<Question> lstRecords = context.questions.GroupBy(x => new { x.QuestionNo, x.ActivityID })
        .Select(g => new Question(){
              QuestionNo = g.Key.QuestionNo, 
              ActivityID = g.Key.ActivityID, 
              joined = string.Join(" ", 
                     g.Select(i => i.QuestionContent + "[" + i.Answer + "]"))})
       .Take(30)
       .ToList();
}
```

Comment: thx for your time and effort in helping ,e  i get this error whereby x doesn't exist in current context.

Comment: hi i have updated with your answer and i got some error , see above thanks man . is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: @user2376998 problem is your return type it is not `IList<Model.question>`

Comment: sorry newbie here . so u mean it does not return a list?

Comment: hi man , thanks for your updated answer , there is an error with context.questions.ToList(); , it says an explicit conversion exists